# Why would *&param be used in a function?

Tags: c++, parameters, llvm

I've been trying to make sense of LLVM's instruction combining code and noticed this function:

```
static void detectLog2OfHalf(Value *&Op, Value *&Y, IntrinsicInst *&Log2) {

   if (!Op->hasOneUse())
     return;

   IntrinsicInst *II = dyn_cast<IntrinsicInst>(Op);
   if (!II)
     return;
   if (II->getIntrinsicID() != Intrinsic::log2 || !II->hasUnsafeAlgebra())
     return;
   Log2 = II;

   Value *OpLog2Of = II->getArgOperand(0);
   if (!OpLog2Of->hasOneUse())
     return;

   Instruction *I = dyn_cast<Instruction>(OpLog2Of);
   if (!I)
     return;
   if (I->getOpcode() != Instruction::FMul || !I->hasUnsafeAlgebra())
     return;

   if (match(I->getOperand(0), m_SpecificFP(0.5)))
     Y = I->getOperand(1);
   else if (match(I->getOperand(1), m_SpecificFP(0.5)))
     Y = I->getOperand(0);
}
```

Why would `*&` by used in the parameters? Does it have some meaning or would `Op` be equivalent to `*&Op`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why would *& by used in the parameters?

In a function parameter list, this parameter

```
IntrinsicInst *&Log2
```

is a reference to pointer to `Value`. It means the function can modify the pointer itself, and this is seen at the caller side. In this case, that happens here:

```
Log2 = II;
```

If `Log2` was not passed by reference, the above line would only have an effect in the scope of the function.

> ... would Op be equivalent to *&Op?

Not in this context. In a different one, yes. For example, when `*` is the de-reference operator and `&` is the address-of operator, then `*&x` would mean "de-reference the result of applying the address-of operator to `x`", that is, de-reference a pointer to `x`. C++ confusingly re-uses symbols depending on context. Most of this is inherited from C. On top of that, changes to C++ should not break existing code. The easiest way to do this is to re-use symbols.

Comment: Thank you. I was told that generally `*` and `&` cancel each other out, does this only apply to single scope then? **Edit**: By apply I mean cancel

Comment: @asimes They can do, in different circumstances. When `*` means "pointer de-reference" and `&` means "address-of" then yes. C++ inherits its creative and confusing re-use of symbols from C.

Answer (score 1):

`&` means reference.
`value *`  means `value` is a pointer.

`value *&op` is equalent to passing pointer by reference, so if we change `value` in the function it will be reflected in the called function.